# Calculated_SQL Table - Search

Tags: google-app-maker

i have done a calculated sql with a custom query.

Implemented a table from that data model.
Until here we are ok.

My problem is the next step:
In my custom query i have a field concatAll(that is all fields concatenated).
In my page i want to put a search box to do a "contains" search in my field concatAll and present those results in my table.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Tried multiple approaches, but could not have the result.

Thanks

Comment: Have you take a look at search implementation in Project Tracker template? - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/

Comment: Hello Pavel, 

cant open the template: Application requires Google Cloud SQL, please contact your Administrator.

Comment: Here are instructions how to setup personal (custom) Cloud SQL instance - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql, and domain-shared one - https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053 (instructions for domain admin)

Comment: Hey Pavel, 

Still can't connect to that template :(

Can you share the relevant snips of code to this search? Basically we have a calculated_sql and one of the fields is all fields concatenated (ConcatAll).

This will be just a search to reduce rows in a table.

Regards

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shkleinik/c7168bbcfa724a3c34868721a28ac230

Comment: Hello Pavel, 

Thanks for the Help we reach a solution basically with that code.
Basically was a param in the query to solve that all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pavel Shkleinik send to me this is possible using :params in the query of calculated_sql.
Example:
or  (c.phone like concat(CONCAT("%", ifnull(:concatAll,''), "%")))
and you put concatAll as a string parameter on datasource page.

Regards